# How to cycle a variable in a given range in python

Tags: python

is there an easy way in python to cycle a variable in a given range?
For example:
Given a range(), I want a variable goes like this:
0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3... till some conditions are satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [`cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) the sequence `0, 1, ..., n, n-1, ..., 1`.
You can easily build this sequence using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)

```
from itertools import chain, cycle

def make_base_sequence(n):
    base = range(n+1)                   # 0, ..., n
    rev_base = reversed(range(1, n))    # n-1, ..., 1
    return chain(base, rev_base)        # 0, ..., n, n-1, ..., 1

for x in cycle(make_base_sequence(5)):
    print(x)
```

Sample run:

```
In [2]: from itertools import chain, cycle
   ...: 
   ...: def make_base_sequence(n):
   ...:     base = range(n+1)
   ...:     rev_base = reversed(range(1, n))
   ...:     return chain(base, rev_base)
   ...: 
   ...: for i, x in enumerate(cycle(make_base_sequence(5))):
   ...:     print(x, end=' ')
   ...:     if i > 20:
   ...:         break
   ...:     
0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `itertools.cycle()`, see here:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle

Answer (score 0):

you need [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.cycle#itertools.cycle):

demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> count = 0
>>> for x in itertools.cycle(range(3)): 
...     if count == 10:
...         break
...     print x,
...     count += 1
... 
0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0
```

Comment: This is invalid code, you check "count" and you assign to it but you never initialize it. (Also, "count" is a bad name for a variable IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.cycle` is a good start. Else you can program it yourself:

```
cycle = [0,1,2,3,2,1]
i = 0
while some_condition:
    value = cycle[i]
    i = (i+1) % len(cycle)
    #do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools

def f(cycle_range, condition_func):
    sequence = range(cycle_range) + range(cycle_range)[-2:0:-1]
    cycle_generator = itertools.cycle(sequence)
    while not condition_func():
        yield next(cycle_generator)

def condition_func():
    """Checks some condition"""
```

Essentially, you just want to loop and constantly check the condition. And each time yeild the next item from the cycle. Now, admittedly there are better ways to check a condition than a function call, but this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def cycle(range_):
    num = -1
    current = 0
    a=time.time()
    while 1:
        print current
        if current in (0, range_):
            num*=-1
        current += num
        if time.time() - a > 0.002:
            break

cycle(3)
```

output:

```
0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 2
```